# Where does this definition of convex set come from?

Tags: convex-analysis, definition

My textbook says the following.

> We call a set $E\subset R^k$ convex if $$\lambda x+(1-\lambda ) y\in E$$
>   whenever $x\in E, y\in E, 0<\lambda <1.$

I'm totally at a loss as to what this definition is trying to tell me.

Wikipedia elaborates by saying

> In other words, every point on the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ is in [$E$].

But I still don't know what that has to do with the above definition. Where does this come from?

Comment: To parametrize a segment in Euclidean space, you can express it as (y-x)t+x, for $t\in[0,1]$, expanding this and redistributing you get your definition.

Comment: Oh, because (x-y) is the slope.

Comment: Oops, I meant y-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps think about it like this - in concrete terms

If $\lambda =\frac 1 2$ the point $\frac 12 x +\frac 12 y$ is half way between $x$ and $y$.

If $\lambda =\frac 1 3$ the point $\frac 13 x +\frac 23 y$ is two thirds third of the way from $x$ and $y$.

So as the values of $\lambda$ vary from $1$ to $0$ you get further from $x$ and closer to $y$ along the straight line which joined the two points.

---

To find a point $0.4$ of the way from $x$ to $y$ start at $x$ and go $0.4$ of the way to obtain $x+0.4(y-x)=0.6x+0.4y=0.6x+(1-0.6)y$